# What does this err means?Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [verifyLoginWithCorrectCredential] with [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Im new with selenium automation. I was just trying to automate a basic login page and I got this error.
I ve created 3 pages which is as follows:
BaseClass:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class BaseClass {
    WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
  public  void BeforeMethod(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Driver\\LatestChrome\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("my url");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }}
```

LoginPageTest:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import ElementRepository.LoginPage;

public class LoginPageTest extends BaseClass {
    LoginPage lp;
  @Test
  public void verifyLoginWithCorrectCredential(String name,String pass) {
      lp = new LoginPage(driver);
      lp.sendUserName("admin");
     lp.sendPassword("admin");
  }
}
```

LoginPage:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class LoginPage {
    WebDriver driver;
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);// with page factory
    }
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Username']")
    WebElement userNameField;
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Password']")
    WebElement passwordField;
    public void sendUserName(String username) {
        userNameField.sendKeys(username);
    }
    public void sendPassword(String password) {
        passwordField.sendKeys(password);
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Test`-annotated methods should not have parameters, and your `verifyLoginWithCorrectCredential` method has two parameters.